# TypeOrm Joins without using QueryBuilder

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, nestjs-swagger

I have 3 tables

1. attendance
2. user
3. attendance_verification.

attendance->ManyToOne->user

attendance->OneToOne->attendanceVerification

now I want to query attendance for a specific user and want to embed complete user and attendanceVerification data in attendance object and return it.
This is what I have tried but it is giving me error **Invalid syntax near where**.

I have tried

```
 const listOfAttendance = await this.attendanceRepository.find({
      where: {
        punchInDateTime: Between(dateFrom, dateTo),
      },
      order: {
        id: 'ASC',
      },
      join: {
        alias: 'attendance',
        leftJoinAndSelect: {
          user: 'attendance.user',
          outlet: 'attendance.outlet',
          punchAck: 'attendance.punchAck',
          verification: 'attendance.attendanceVerification',
        },
      },
    })
```

**Query being parsed by TypeORM**

```
        SELECT
  "attendance"."id" AS "attendance_id",
  "attendance"."punchInImage" AS "attendance_punchInImage",
  "attendance"."punchInDateTime" AS "attendance_punchInDateTime",
  "attendance"."punchInComment" AS "attendance_punchInComment",
  "attendance"."punchOutDateTime" AS "attendance_punchOutDateTime",
  "attendance"."punchOutComment" AS "attendance_punchOutComment",
  "attendance"."punchOutImage" AS "attendance_punchOutImage",
  "attendance"."status" AS "attendance_status",
  "attendance"."approvalStatus" AS "attendance_approvalStatus",
  "attendance"."userId" AS "attendance_userId",
  "attendance"."outletId" AS "attendance_outletId",
  "attendance"."createdAt" AS "attendance_createdAt",
  "user"."id" AS "user_id",
  "user"."firstName" AS "user_firstName",
  "user"."lastName" AS "user_lastName",
  "user"."userName" AS "user_userName",
  "user"."contact" AS "user_contact",
  "user"."gender" AS "user_gender",
  "user"."dob" AS "user_dob",
  "user"."country" AS "user_country",
  "user"."state" AS "user_state",
  "user"."postalCode" AS "user_postalCode",
  "user"."isAdmin" AS "user_isAdmin",
  "user"."isEmployee" AS "user_isEmployee",
  "user"."byEmail" AS "user_byEmail",
  "user"."byContact" AS "user_byContact",
  "user"."address" AS "user_address",
  "user"."email" AS "user_email",
  "user"."orgId" AS "user_orgId",
  "user"."password" AS "user_password",
  "user"."salt" AS "user_salt",
  "user"."createdBy" AS "user_createdBy",
  "user"."status" AS "user_status",
  "user"."apiAccessKey" AS "user_apiAccessKey",
  "user"."createdAt" AS "user_createdAt",
  "user"."metaId" AS "user_metaId",
  "outlet"."id" AS "outlet_id",
  "outlet"."name" AS "outlet_name",
  "outlet"."comment" AS "outlet_comment",
  "outlet"."location" AS "outlet_location",
  "outlet"."status" AS "outlet_status",
  "outlet"."orgId" AS "outlet_orgId",
  "outlet"."validated" AS "outlet_validated",
  "punchAck"."id" AS "punchAck_id",
  "punchAck"."isPunchedIn" AS "punchAck_isPunchedIn",
  "punchAck"."isAck" AS "punchAck_isAck",
  "punchAck"."userId" AS "punchAck_userId",
  "punchAck"."dateTime" AS "punchAck_dateTime",
  "punchAck"."rejectComment" AS "punchAck_rejectComment",
  "punchAck"."attendanceId" AS "punchAck_attendanceId",
  "verification"."id" AS "verification_id",
  "verification"."status" AS "verification_status",
  "verification"."punchIn" AS "verification_punchIn",
  "verification"."punchOut" AS "verification_punchOut",
  "verification"."supervisorId" AS "verification_supervisorId",
  "verification"."attendanceId" AS "verification_attendanceId",
  "verification"."comment" AS "verification_comment",
  "verification"."createdAt" AS "verification_createdAt"
FROM
  "tenant"."attendance" "attendance"
  LEFT JOIN "tenant"."users" "user" ON "user"."id" = "attendance"."userId"
  LEFT JOIN "tenant"."outlet" "outlet" ON "outlet"."id" = "attendance"."outletId"
  LEFT JOIN "tenant"."punch_ack" "punchAck" ON "punchAck"."attendanceId" = "attendance"."id"
  LEFT JOIN "tenant"."attendance_verification" "verification" ON
WHERE
  "attendance"."punchInDateTime" BETWEEN $ 1
  AND $ 2
ORDER BY
  "attendance"."id" ASC
        PARAMETERS:[
  "2021-02-28T19:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-31T18:59:59.000Z"
]
```

**AttendanceEntity (Exluded some fields to make code clean)**

```
import { ApiPropertyOptional } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm'
import { AttendanceVerification } from '@modules/attendance/attendance-verification/attendance_verification.entity'
import { Break } from '@modules/attendance/break/break.entity'
import { PunchAck } from '@modules/attendance/punch-ack/punch_ack.entity'
import { Outlet } from '@modules/outlet/outlet.entity'
import { User } from '@modules/users/users.entity'

@Entity('attendance')
export class Attendance extends BaseEntity {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @Column()
  punchInImage: string

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @Column({ type: 'timestamp' })
  punchInDateTime: Date

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @Column()
  approvalStatus: string

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @Column()
  userId: number

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @Column()
  outletId: number

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.attendance)
  user: User

  @OneToOne(type => Outlet, outlet => outlet.attendance)
  outlet: Outlet

  @OneToMany(type => Break, breaks => breaks.attendance)
  breaks: Break[]

  @OneToMany(type => PunchAck, punchAck => punchAck.attendance)
  punchAck: PunchAck[]

  @OneToOne(
    type => AttendanceVerification,
    attendanceVerification => attendanceVerification.attendance
  )
  attendanceVerification: AttendanceVerification
}
```

All solutions I find on internet uses queryBuilder. I don't want to use that lengthy method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From typeorm docs: https://typeorm.io/#/find-options
You can use something like:

```
userRepository.find({
    join: {
        alias: "user",
        leftJoinAndSelect: {
            profile: "user.profile",
            photo: "user.photos",
            video: "user.videos"
        }
    }
});
```

Or your example may look like:

```
const returnedResult = await this.attendanceRepository.findOne({
      where: { userId: id, status: 'PUNCHED IN' },
      join: {
         alias: "attendance",
         leftJoinAndSelect: {
            user: "attendance.user",
            outlet: "attendance.outlet",
        }
      },
    });
```

From my personal experience if you'd need to write complex queries you have to work with QueryBuilder. It looks awkward on the first glance only.

Comment: [Nest] 4444   - 03/18/2021, 2:59:07 PM   [PostgreSQL] error: syntax error at or near "WHERE" +22ms

Comment: how to paste query which is typeOrM is generating here in comment? its too long.

Comment: Part of query near Where --> FROM
      "tenent1"."attendance" "attendance"
      LEFT JOIN "tenent1"."users" "user" ON "user"."id" = "attendance"."userId"
      LEFT JOIN "tenent1"."outlet" "outlet" ON
    WHERE
      "attendance"."userId" = $ 1
      AND "attendance"."status" = $ 2
  ) "distinctAlias"
ORDER BY
  "attendance_id" ASC

Comment: any help? anything??

Comment: sorry wasn't able to chat. Have you done this? Can you send a full query if it's still applicable

Comment: i have updated question with more detail. can you guide me what is the issue with query?